# Run both local and global git hooks

Tags: git, githooks

I have a global git hook `post-commit` which is situated under:

```
~/.git_templates/hooks/post-commit
```

I have made it global by

```
git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_templates'
```

and using `git init` to update the settings for my git project.

Yet one project had its own `post-commit` hook under:

```
~/src/git.repo/.git/hooks/post-commit
```

The local one ran but prevented the global one from running. How can I achieve that both are run on post commit?

I want to avoid adding the command in the local post commit hook.

Comment: You can't.  Your repo is yours, theirs is theirs, only keeping repos entirely self-contained absent explicit local coding keeps that true.

Comment: @jthill It's a pity, as there are use cases for hooks that are only relevant for my own sake (e.g. like taking a photo on commit via webcam) vs. hooks that should only run from the local hook space (e.g. a pre-commit hook enforcing a certain code style). I do understand why it makes sense to keep certain hooks local only, yet not all. I think it would be nice to have something on the lines of a hook domain. Anyhow, can you reference a source for the claim of yours and expand your comment into an answer? I most likely would, albeit begrudgingly, accept it.

Comment: "[Hooks are little scripts you can place in $GIT_DIR/hooks directory to trigger action at certain points.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_description)". 

That's all there is to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a global hook path.

```bash
git config --global core.hooksPath "$CONFIG_DIR/hooks"
```

This will ignore local hook and run global hook scripts only.

And **if you want to run both local & global hook**, you can call local hook from global hook manually.

For example: call this script from your global `pre-commit` hook.

```
...
/path/to/run-local-hook pre-commit
```

`run-local-hook` file:

```bash
# Run local hook if exists
HOOK=$1
PROJECT_ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

if [ -e "$PROJECT_ROOT/.git/hooks/$HOOK" ]; then
  $PROJECT_ROOT/.git/hooks/$HOOK "$@"
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: There is missing quotes to correctly handle paths with spaces
# Run local hook if exists
HOOK=$1
PROJECT_ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

if [ -e "$PROJECT_ROOT/.git/hooks/$HOOK" ]; then
  "$PROJECT_ROOT/.git/hooks/$HOOK" "$@"
else
  exit 0
fi

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be:

- to make sure your global hook is deployed for all your users
- modify your global hook to call a pre-agreed script which can be set by the users if they want to. For instance `$GIT_DIR/hooks/my-post-commit`

`my-post-commit` is not a standard [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks) name, so it won't be run automatically by Git.
Only your global hook will, and it will call the client custom script setup by the user.

That doesn't change the fact that, if a local `$GIT_DIR/hooks/post-commit` does exist, that would still prevent your global hook to run.